# Is it possible using an "AND"-operator for "ConditionalAttribute"?

Tags: c#, conditional-compilation

Is it possible to use an`AND`-operator like this `[Conditional("DEBUG")&& Conditional("ANNA")]` ?

Using an `OR`-operator works: `[Conditional("DEBUG"),Conditional("ANNA")]`.

Comment: Comma != logical OR...........

Answer (score 1):

No, that isn't supported as far as I'm aware. I would suggest just defining a third symbol in that case. (I'd also try to do *all* of this really, really sparingly...)